# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am writing bot using discord.py and selenium. Code runs normally on my computer, but when I try to deploy it on server, an NoSuchDriverException occurs. Before running code I've installed everything using requirements.txt.

Code:

```
import asyncio
import functools
import time
import typing
from converters import *

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re


def scrap():
    url = 'https://www.cryptocraft.com/calendar?week=this'

    op = Options()

    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'

    op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    op.add_argument("--headless")
    op.add_argument("start-maximized")
    op.add_argument("window-size=1900,1080")
    op.add_argument("disable-gpu")
    op.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
    op.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    op.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    op.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    op.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    op.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
    
    ...
```

Logs:

```
File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 126, in run
    completed_proc = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1950, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 95, in driver_location
    output = self.run(args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 132, in run
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}") from err
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: /home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager --browser chrome --output json
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 239, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/app.py", line 47, in send_news
    res = await run_blocking(scrap)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/app.py", line 30, in run_blocking
    return await client.loop.run_in_executor(None, func)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/scraper.py", line 37, in scrap
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

`requirements.txt: selenium==4.12.0 discord==2.3.2 pytz==2023.3`

I've tried different options (including no options), but the error still appears. Some options, like user agent, are required to get data from website.

Comment: "_Code runs normally on my computer, but when I try to deploy it on server, an NoSuchDriverException occurs_" - This seems to be an easy problem to fix. Either the web driver is not on the server at the specified path, or you are not calling the correct method to obtain the resource (web driver). What have you tried to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: @hfontanez I've tried chromedriver_autoinstaller and ChromeDriverManager but they dont work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic download of appropriate chromedriver for Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017043/automatic-download-of-appropriate-chromedriver-for-selenium-in-python)

Comment: @hfontanez It seems not. What do I need to install on the server for the code to work?

Comment: Good question. If the linked Stack Overflow posting doesn't work for you, I am really at a loss. Could it be a permissions issue in the server you're using? That would be my guess. If not, I suggest putting a comment on the linked question under one of the provided answers and see if they could help you.